# How can I get product list using related product?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have to get product list using related product, which product added in simple product as a related product. I have pass reveser query.

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find my question of answer.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')
                ->getCollection();
$related_products = $collection->getData();

foreach ($related_products as $_product){
$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product['linked_product_id']);
}
```

Its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass product id for which you require related product.

E.g You need related product for a particular product (Say $_product)

You can get related product ids by

```
 $_product->getRelatedProductIds()
```

You can see array of ids by :

```
 print_r($_product->getRelatedProductIds());
```

I hope this will help you.

Regards, Manju

Comment: It wouldn't work for me. I have found solution for it. But thank you for your answer.